# Fragment in a dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've seen this question before but I haven't really found a nice, streamlined answer to it. I have a fragment that I want to display as a dialog on large screen devices but normally for anything else.

Is there something like a FragmentDialogWrapper out there?

In c# (xamarin)

```
var fragment = new DetailFragment();
if(_isLarge)
{
    var wrapper = new FragmentDialogWrapper(fragment);
    wrapper.MagicallyDisplay();
}
else
{
    fragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.content, fragment);
}
```

Thanks

// Johan

Comment: use the dialogFragment..

Comment: Is it possible to add a class that inherits from DialogFragment to a "regular" view (the second clause in my code sample)? That is I don't have to manage two DetailFragments?

Comment: That worked perfectly... So simple. Post it as an answer so you can get the points. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DialogFragment. As it is a Fragment and a dialog.